# What preposition: "on the mobile" or "in the mobile"?

Tags: prepositions, word-usage

I read this:

> The battery's flat on the mobile.

I think we should say *in the mobile* not *on the mobile*.

Comment: I'd use 'The mobile's battery's flat', but would choose 'on' rather than 'in' if pressed. It's an intermediate (semi-locative, semi-metaphorical) usage of 'on', cf 'on the train', 'The rear tyre on the car's flat'. Though I'd not use this as proof, and this is metaphorical, this AHDEL definition for _on_ lends support: 9. Used to indicate belonging to: _a nurse on the hospital staff_. Collins comes closer with: 2. attached to: _a puppet on a string_.

Comment: Of course, in the US if you said your mobile's battery is flat we'd advise you to call the AAA.

Comment: Most mobile homes do not run on batteries anyway, but if they did, then the battery would be ***in*** the mobile.  Tires, now, tires can go flat on a mobile, especially tires on old Winnebegos. But batteries, I don’t imagine so.  What’s a flat battery anyway?

Answer (score 1):

If I must choose, I'd say *on*, but a case could be made for *in* as well, as the battery is *inside* the mobile phone.

This is going to be a non-answer, but I would honestly just say this instead:

> The mobile's battery's flat.

Avoids the problem and sounds far more natural.

Comment: in the us we use 'dead', flat must be British?

Comment: According to Google ngram, *flat* and *dead* are about as common in British English, while in American English *dead* is about six times as popular.

Comment: @kns98 See *[Battery is flat](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131427)* and *[“I have no charge on my cellphone” or “my cellphone is out of charge”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10084)* for previous discussions of deadness vs. flatness.